# Differences (or similarity) between Radon-Nikodym and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

What's the difference, or similarity, between the Radon-Nikodym theorem and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral?  In Radon-Nikodym, under the proper assumptions, we can shove a function from the integral into the measure
$$
\int_A f \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu = \int_Af d\nu
$$
However, this also seems possible with a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral since it seems like we can have
$$
\int_A f g^\prime d\mu = \int_A f dg
$$
As such, what's the fundamental difference between the two tools?

Comment: Not every Lebesgue stieltjies measure is absolutely continuous and thus need not satisfy the assumptions of randon nikodym

Comment: @aduh if the measure is omitted, it is usually the Lebesgue measure. In context of Lebesgue stieltjies it also makes senses. Every measure is obviously AC wrt itself. And radon nikodym basically only requires AC and Sigma finiteness. What exactly do you need to know?